# How do I Filter TopN in Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) based on the subgroup of a Chart with multi-level grouping?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, mdx

**Q: how do I get the top N columns from a multi-level grouping in a Reporting Services Chart, whilst maintaining correct labeling for the top level groups?**

To save the time of anyone who want to add a TopN filter to a single grouping in a Chart, and have been led here by the title of the question, see here:-

[How to: Add a Filter (Reporting Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156270(v=sql.100).aspx)

[Filter Equation Examples (Reporting Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627464(v=sql.100).aspx)

I have a more complex issue. I have two Category Groups in a Chart, Area and Unit.
[image]

When I run my report I get a lot of Units plotted, but **I just want to get the top top 3 Unit level counts (i.e. top 3 highest columns)**:-
[image]

If I apply a TopN filter at the Area group level, I get the top 3 Areas by sum of columns, which is not unexpected.

[image]

If I apply a TopN filter at the Unit group level, then I get this arrangement of groups, notice that the 5 items in Blok_11 has now become 3, so the TopN is being applied inside each Area group: -

[image]

If I add a Unit sub-group to my Area group as shown below, then I get the correct three columns, but the items are not grouped by Area in the axis label: -

[image]

Incorrect grouping by Area:-

[image]

I am assuming that there is a correct solution to this, or is there a workaround?

By the way, I am using a shared Dataset which is used in a tablix to display all the data from the Dataset, so there is no opportunity to perform a TopN on the data itself. Due to impact upon report delivery times I am reluctant to add a second dataset just for the chart.

Comment: what is the MDX code that is being questioned? You added an MDX tag but I can't see any

Comment: @whytheq, I added the MDX tag so that I didn't get any T-SQL server-side solutions to the problem. I was attempting to solicit solutions in the Reporting Services Report, but I am thinking that this is not possible, and that the solution might require a change to the MDX query, possibly using the Ranking function?

Answer (score 1):

On SQL-Server side you can use a `SELECT` query with a `TOP` clause together with an `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT TOP 3 SomeValue
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY SomeValue
```

Will return the three highest values

You can use `TOP()` to send in the counter as a variable

```
DECLARE @Counter INT=3;
SELECT TOP (@Counter) SomeValue
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY SomeValue
```

I'd use an *inline table valued function* as data source and pass the counter to this function as parameter.

Comment: I'm using MDX, but I get the idea, and it may be a viable workaround for others. My problem is that the chart lives in a report with a tablix that diplays a different TOPN (many more rows in the table than columns in the chart), so I would need a separate data set for the chart. Unfortunately the current query is quite slow, so I would be reluctant to "double up" as it would impact on report delivery time.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213360/create-a-dataset-which-is-a-subset-of-another-dataset-in-ssrs you can't do what you suggest with Reporting Services Datasets.

Comment: @BarrieK That's why I wrote *on SQL Server Side*. I was thinking of a select/View/iTVF on top of another one